# How do I stop the [Required] annotation from being inherited on overridden fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I've got a model for a phone number notification (users get notified of emergencies via phone numbers that they associate with their account, and they can set what order these are called in). Most of the time, the phone number part of the model is required, but there's a special case during creation of a new user where we don't want to force it.

I made a very simple child object UserCreationPhoneNotificationModel that inherits from the above described UserPhoneNotificationModel. There's a couple other small changes, but the relevant one here is overriding the PhoneNumber field so that it's no longer required.

In the parent model it's

```
[Required]
public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

And in the child model it's just

```
public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

I figured this would do the trick, but apparently not. I thought the issue would be that RequiredAttribute would have Inherited = true on it, but it doesn't so I'm not entirely sure why it's being inherited into the subclass.

I did double check to make sure, and removing Required from the field in the parent also made the field in the subclass not required, so it's definitely some kind of inheritance thing.

Comment: RequiredAttribute inherits from Attribute through ValidationAttribute. The abstract class Attribute has Inherited = true.
You're better off using a custom attribute in your scenario and setting the Inherited flag to false.

Comment: Ah, I had just realized I hadn't looked further up the chain. Seems sort of silly to create a new attribute just to turn off Inherited, but it does look like that's the only way to go.

Comment: Have you tried setting the phonenumber to hide the base implementation by giving it the new keyword?

Comment: General advise for easier and cleaner development in .net mvc:  Favor composition over inheritance--use view models--place your annotations on the vm, closer to the ui where they are needed.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done by **Hiding** the existing Property by a new property of the same name.
So, if the property is like this in the parent class:

```
[Required]
public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

You can define the new property in the child class like this:

```
public new string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

This will hide the PhoneNumber Property along with its Attributes in the child class. Now you can use any other attributes with it. For example, you can add `[PhoneNumber]` attribute to the property in the child class.

Comment: This implementation threw a `The property 'PhoneNumber' on the content type 'UserCreationPhoneNotificationModel' is autogenerated but not virtual declared` exception for me. I had to define the property in the child class as follows:

```public new virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }```

Answer (score 4):

Using inheritance to share behaviour when the relationship you're modelling doesn't fit can be problematic. You do not typically get any benefit from using inheritance to share behaviour between ViewModels, while you can (and, as in your case, *do*) encounter problems.

Your best bet is to use a different model class for each use-case. If you genuinely need to share behaviour between ViewModels, you can do so with composition.

Answer (score -1):

below example may be help you.

```
public class SigninModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public virtual string email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

This is Signin Model and i have inherit to another model but email is not required it's code as below:

```
public class ExternalLoginModel : SigninModel
{
    public override string email { get; set; }
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
}
```

I have override the email property in another model

Answer (score -2):

If Using C# 4.0,

How about writing the 'new' Constructor.

```
public new string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure that it works good.

Comment: Perhaps you can test this before posting as answer.

Answer (score -2):

**It makes no sense to not inherit an attribute**.

Removing the `[Required]` attribute when overriding essentially violates **[LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)**.

> *If `NotRequiredDerived` is a subtype of `RequiredBase`, then objects of type `RequiredBase` may be replaced with objects of type `NotRequiredDerived` (i.e. an object of type `RequiredBase` may be substituted with any object of a subtype `NotRequiredDerived`) without altering any of the desirable properties of the program.*

To put it in simple code:

```
var requiredPhoneNumber = new RequiredBase() { PhoneNumber = "123456789" };

HandleRequiredBaseObject(requiredPhoneNumber); //Works

var optionalPhoneNumber = new NotRequiredDerived() { PhoneNumber = null };

HandleRequiredBaseObject(optionalPhoneNumber); //Fails
```

`HandleRequiredBaseObject(RequiredBase obj)` inherently assumes that the `PhoneNumber` is required (as per the definition of the `RequiredBase` class); and it's not expecting to received a derived object which lacks this constraint! This is going to result in runtime exceptions.

The only way to not violate LSP would be to ensure that the `[Required]` constraint is not violated on derived classes; which means that there's no point to trying to remove the `[Required]` annotation in the first place.

---

I can think of one **theoretical** case where not inheriting the attribute would make sense: if the attribute *expands* the range of valid options, as opposed to limiting it.

Suppose we make a class `PositiveNumber` and an attribute that sets it to also allow negative numbers:

```
public class Base 
{
    [NegativesAllowed]
    public PositiveNumber Number { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public PositiveNumber Number { get; set; }
}
```

If `Base` allows all numbers, and `Derived` only allows positive numbers, then it doesn't inherently violate LSP.

However, this seems like a very forced situation. Using a *limited* type which is then broadened by an attribute is not something you're going to realistically encounter.

---

For your case, you simply shouldn't be inheriting one viewmodel from another.

The fact that there are different attributes required is the main reason why you shouldn't be inheriting these classes! They are supposed to work differently from one another, and therefore should not pretend like one is a derivation of the other.