# Is there any way to disable the validation of inherited properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-validation

I have the following entities for example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class FirstChildClass: BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SecondChildClas: BaseClass
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then i have the following viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public FirstChildClass FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public SecondChildClass SecondProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In my View i have a form which submits the following properties *FirstChildClass.Id* and *SecondChildClass.Id*.

My problem is that the inherited DisplayName is added to my ModelState due to the [Required] attribute. I'd like to ignore the validation of inherited properties without removing them explicitly from the ModelState with Remove().

Is there any way to accomplish it?

Comment: Maybe it will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957495/how-do-i-stop-the-required-annotation-from-being-inherited-on-overridden-field

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using inheritance here. What is `BaseClass`:

> I have `DisplayName` and it should be `Required` but not always, it depends, looks in all derived classes to understand how I work.

If you really want to go that way check if you can make this property virtual, and add attribute only to one derived class.